# Esper: How to query in an array in Json

Tags: json, esper

I created a json scheme using "@public @buseventtype create json schema ArrayEvent(carId string, direction int[])" and I want to write a statement to select from ArrayEvent where its direction list contains 5. For example, there are 2 following events:

```
String event1 = "{" +
                "  \"carId\" : \"B123456\",\n" +
                "  \"direction\" : [\"1\", \"2\"]\n" +
                "}" 

String event2 = "{" +
                "  \"carId\" : \"B123456\",\n" +
                "  \"direction\" : [\"4\", \"5\"]\n" +
                "}"
```

Then event2 is expected to be selected. How should I write a statement to select from the json format event, which contains array?

Answer (score 0):

You could use "anyOf".

```
select * from Event(direction.anyOf(v => v = 5))
```